# Not receiving any request information in my NestJs Middleware set up

Tags: angular, middleware, nestjs

I have a NestJs and Angular app.  It took some time to get a "production" version running and I was able to eventually figure it out using a setup like so in my main.ts server file:

```js
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(CLIENT_FILES + '/index.html');
});
```

In now trying to move to an implemented middleware:

I've been working off of Bo's example here to implement middleware: https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/use-nest-as-your-server-side-application-with-an-angular-frontend-540b0365bfa3

My middleware is getting hit for every request but I cannot get any information from the Request parameter so nothing is taking place and the app itself hangs.  I'm not sure what step I missed or if I have an existing setup that is preventing visibility into the request object.  Any direction is much appreciated

Below are my logs from the middleware:

Results
da req get path :  /
 da req get originalUrl :  /
 da req get hostname :  localhost
 da req get baseUrl :
 da req get url:  /

my frontendmiddleware.ts:

```js
import { NestMiddleware, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { join } from 'path';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

const allowedExt = [
    '.js',
    '.ico',
    '.css',
    '.png',
    '.jpg',
    '.woff2',
    '.woff',
    '.ttf',
    '.svg',
  ];

  const ROUTE_PREFIX = 'api';
  const resolvePath = (file: string) => join(__dirname, '..', file);


  @Injectable()
  export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {

    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {

       console.log('da req : ' + req );
       console.log( ' da req get path :  ' + req.path);
       console.log( ' da req get originalUrl :  ' + req.originalUrl);
       console.log( ' da req get hostname :  ' + req.hostname);
       console.log( ' da req get baseUrl :  ' + req.baseUrl);
   console.log( ' da req get url:  ' + req.url );

        const { url } = req; 

        if (url.indexOf(ROUTE_PREFIX) === 1) {
          // it starts with /api --> continue with execution
          next();
        } else if (allowedExt.filter(ext => url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
          // it has a file extension --> resolve the filea
          console.log('here be the other files: ' + resolvePath(url));
          res.sendFile(resolvePath(url));
        } else {
          // in all other cases, redirect to the index.html!
          res.sendFile(resolvePath('index.html'));
        }
    }


  }
```

my app.module.ts

```js
import { Module, NestModule, RequestMethod, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ConfigurationService } from './shared/configuration/configuration.service';
import { Configuration } from './shared/configuration/configuration.enum';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { FrontendMiddleware } from './middleware/frontend.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(ConfigurationService.connectionString),
    UserModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {

  constructor(private readonly configurationService: ConfigurationService) {
    AppModule.port = AppModule.normalizePort(configurationService.get(Configuration.PORT));
    AppModule.host = configurationService.get(Configuration.HOST);
    AppModule.isDev = configurationService.isDevelopment;

    console.log('port : ' + AppModule.port);
    console.log('host : ' + AppModule.host);
    console.log('isDev : ' + AppModule.isDev);

  }

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(FrontendMiddleware).forRoutes(
        {
          path: '/**', // For all routes
          method: RequestMethod.ALL, // For all methods
        },
      );
  }

  static host: string;
  static port: number | string;
  static isDev: boolean;


  private static normalizePort(param: number | string): number | string {
    const portNumber: number = typeof param === 'string' ? parseInt(param, 10) : param;
    if (isNaN(portNumber)) {
      return param;
    } else if (portNumber >= 0) {
      return portNumber;
    }
  }
}
```

my new main.ts:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './shared/filters/http-exception.filter';
import { join } from 'path';

declare const module: any;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.display(() => app.close());
  }

  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
  app.enableCors();

  await app.listen(AppModule.port);
}
bootstrap();
```

UPDATE -- in workign through the documentation, i was able to get the "functional middleware" working but still no luck with the middleware class ( https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware)

```
export function logger(req, res, next) {
  console.log(`Request...`);
  next();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the two asterisks from the path seemed to make the difference.. I think there's something with my setup leading to these results but this seems to do it for the time being:

path: '/'

Comment: Same case for me, looks like nestjs middleware doesn't work with wildcards